# Get post() function from the view function returned by resolve()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I defined a class based on `rest_framework.views.APIView` and added it as a view to some url. For example like:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.urls import path

class MyApi(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        # Do something with the request
        print(request.data)
        return Response(status=200)


path('my-url', MyApi.as_view())
```

In another file, I want to access the `post()` function of that class, but I only know the `url`. So I use the `django.urls.resolve()` function to get the view function.

```py
from django.urls import resolve
view, args, kwargs = resolve(url)
```

However, I don't want to obtain the view function, but the underlying `post()` function that I defined in the API-Class.

Is there any option to get that function while only knowing the `url`?

I want to avoid building a lookup for every possible `url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rest_framework.views.APIView` calls one of its methods based on the requests method. so the function cannot be obtained from the request URL only. it needs both URL and request `method`. for example, if you send a `POST` request to `example/`, it calls the `post` method of your `APIView`. and if you call the same URL with the `GET` method, it calls the `get` method of your view.

from `rest_framework.views.APIView` [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py):

```py
# Get the appropriate handler method
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

so we can do the same.

first, get the view from the `resolve` function:

```py
from django.urls import resolve
view, args, kwargs = resolve(request.URL)
```

then, obtain the handler function from view:

```py
if request.method.lower() in view.http_method_names:
    handler = getattr(view, request.method.lower(),None)
else:
    handler = None
```